# Which Python module to use to record value change over time?

Tags: python, automation, slider, record, timeline

Here is my task. I have a Rasberry PI connected to 2 servo-motors. I want to develop a GUI application which will contain nothing but a record button and 2 slders of Tkinter. Now what I want to do is I want to have a record button which, after being pressed will record all the value changes of the sliders over time of the app. So it will be almost like animating/automating.

This will give me an "animation" of changing value over time. Now I will apply those values to the servomotor and thus they will reproduce the movement based on the recorded values on a timeline. My question is which module do I use to record the value change over time?

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need a special module for this. I would set a callback for the `Scale` element that will log the time and value somewhere. This could be done with something like:

```
import time

positions = []

def changedPosition(value):
    positions.append((time.time(), value))
```

Make sure to pass the changedPosition function as the `command` argument to the `Scale`.